# Save Zsh history to ~/.persistent_history

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

Recently I want to try Z shell in Mac. But I'd like to continue also saving the command history to ~/.persistent_history, which was what I did in Bash ([ref](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/06/11/keeping-persistent-history-in-bash)).

However, the script in the ref link doesn't work under Zsh:

```
log_bash_persistent_history()
{
   [[
     $(history 1) =~ ^\ *[0-9]+\ +([^\ ]+\ [^\ ]+)\ +(.*)$
   ]]
   local date_part="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
   local command_part="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
   if [ "$command_part" != "$PERSISTENT_HISTORY_LAST" ]
   then
     echo $date_part "|" "$command_part" >> ~/.persistent_history
     export PERSISTENT_HISTORY_LAST="$command_part"
   fi
}
run_on_prompt_command()
{
   log_bash_persistent_history
}
PROMPT_COMMAND="run_on_prompt_command"
```

Is there anyone who can help me get it working? Many thanks!

Comment: [This](http://superuser.com/questions/735660/whats-the-zsh-equivalent-of-bashs-prompt-command) should help with replacing `PROMPT_COMMAND`. Replacing the `[[` usage should be doable with `grep -o` or `cut` or similar but depends on the exact output of `history` in zsh.

Comment: @EtanReisner Thanks so much! For the `PROMPT_COMMAND`, the link should be helpful. For `[[` part, I just found with the command `history`, bash will give the newest one (in this case, it's `history`) at the last line. But under Zsh, `history` command won't return the newest one, it returns the command used before `history` at the last line. Any ideas? :-)

Comment: Well, I see no reason in reinventing the wheel. Just set `HISTFILE` and set `HISTSIZE` and `SAVEHIST` to some ridiculously large size (mine are 100,000, and I see no reason to make them larger, since I log all my terminal sessions anyway in iTerm2 — that's all commands + output, with time down to seconds in my prompt). The default history format has POSIX timestamps associated, which is more accurate than yours since yours don't have tzinfo.

Comment: (If you want to combine zsh and bash history — well, that's asking for trouble. The syntax of both shells are incompatible in many ways, especially if you have customized your zsh to a certain extent.)

Comment: @4ae1e1 Yes, you brought up a great point. I'll think about it. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't comment yet (and this went beyond a simple correction), so I'll add this as an answer.

[This correction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38871854/8070745) to [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30272351/8070745) doesn't quite work when, for example, the last command took quite a bit of time to execute - you'll get stray numbers and `;` in your command, like this:

```
2017-07-22 19:02:42 | 3;micro ~/.zshrc && . ~/.zshrc
```

This can be fixed by replacing the `sed -re '1s/.{15}//'` in `command_part` with a slightly longer `gawk`, which also avoids us a pipeline:

```
local command_part="$(gawk "
  NR == $line_num_last {
    pivot = match(\$0, \";\");
    print substr(\$0, pivot+1);
  }
  NR > $line_num_last {
    print;
  }" ~/.zsh_history)"
```

It also has problems when dealing with multiline commands where one of the lines begin with `:`. This can be (mostly) fixed by replacing `grep -ane '^:' ~/.zsh_history` in `line_num_last` with `grep -anE '^: [0-9]{10}:[0-9]*?;' ~/.zsh_history` - I say mostly because a command could conceivably contain a string matching that expression. Say,

```
% naughty "multiline
> command
> : 0123456789:123;but a command I'm not
> "
```

Which will result in a clobbered record in `~/.persistent_history`.

To fix this we need, in turn, to check whether the previous redord ends with `\` (there might be other conditions but I'm not familiar yet with this history format), and if so *try* the previous match.

```
_get_line_num_last () {
  local attempts=0
  local line=0
  while true; do
    # Greps the last two lines that can be considered history records
    local lines="$(grep -anE '^: [0-9]{10}:[0-9]*?;' ~/.zsh_history | \
                 tail -n $((2 + attempts)) | head -2)"
    local previous_line="$(echo "$lines" | head -1)"
    # Gets the line number of the line being tested
    local line_attempt=$(echo "$lines" | tail -1 | cut -d':' -f1 | tr -d '\n')
    # If the previous (possible) history records ends with `\`, then the
    # _current_ one is part of a multiline command; try again.
    # Probably. Unless it was in turn in the middle of a multi-line
    # command. And that's why the last line should be saved.
    if [[ $line_attempt -ne $HISTORY_LAST_LINE ]] && \
       [[ $previous_line == *"\\" ]] && [[ $attempts -eq 0 ]];
    then
      ((attempts+=1))
    else
      line=$line_attempt
      break
    fi
  done
  echo "$line"
}
precmd() {
  local line_num_last="$(_get_line_num_last)"
  local date_part="$(gawk "NR == $line_num_last {print;}" ~/.zsh_history | cut -c 3-12)"
  local fmt_date="$(date -d @${date_part} +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')"
  # I use awk itself to split the _first_ line only at the first `;`
  local command_part="$(gawk "
    NR == $line_num_last {
      pivot = match(\$0, \";\");
      print substr(\$0, pivot+1);
    }
    NR > $line_num_last {
      print;
    }" ~/.zsh_history)"
  if [ "$command_part" != "$PERSISTENT_HISTORY_LAST" ]
  then
    echo "${fmt_date} | ${command_part}" >> ~/.persistent_history
    export PERSISTENT_HISTORY_LAST="$command_part"
    export HISTORY_LAST_LINE=$((1 + $(wc -l < ~/.zsh_history)))
  fi
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late acceptance. You were right about commands beginning with `:`. Thanks for the insightful digging. :-)

Answer (score 6):

After so much Googling, I finally found out the way to do this.
First, in ~/.zshrc, add the following options for history manipulation:

```
setopt append_history # append rather then overwrite
setopt extended_history # save timestamp
setopt inc_append_history # add history immediately after typing a command
```

In short, these three options will record every input_time+command to ~/.zsh_history immediately. 
Then, put this function into ~/.zshrc:

```
precmd() { # This is a function that will be executed before every prompt
    local date_part="$(tail -1 ~/.zsh_history | cut -c 3-12)"
    local fmt_date="$(date -d @${date_part} +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')"
    # For older version of command "date", comment the last line and uncomment the next line
    #local fmt_date="$(date -j -f '%s' ${date_part} +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')"
    local command_part="$(tail -1 ~/.zsh_history | cut -c 16-)"
    if [ "$command_part" != "$PERSISTENT_HISTORY_LAST" ]
    then
        echo "${fmt_date} | ${command_part}"  >> ~/.persistent_history
        export PERSISTENT_HISTORY_LAST="$command_part"
    fi
}
```

Since I use both bash and zsh, so I want a file that can save all their history commands. In this case, I can easily search all of them using "grep".

Comment: This fails with multi line commands. The following works: `local date_part="$(gawk 'substr($0, 0, 1) == ":" {print;}' ~/.zsh_history | tail -1  | cut -c 3-12)"`

Comment: `append_history` and `inc_append_history` are mutually exclusive btw. Specifying them both does nothing in addition to just setting `inc_append_history`.

Based on my reading of [Zsh's options](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html), `append_history`, `inc_append_history`, `inc_append_history_time`, and `share_history` are all mutually exclusive.

Comment: @KeithDevens Sorry, where exactly did you find `append_history` and `inc_append_history` are mutually exclusive in the documentation?

Comment: @astroboylrx from the descriptions in the docs I linked. For example, the docs say `inc_append_history` "...works like `APPEND_HISTORY` except that new history lines are added to the `$HISTFILE` incrementally". So there's no need to specify both `append_history` and `inc_append_history`. `inc_append_history_time` is more explicit: "This option is only useful if `INC_APPEND_HISTORY` and `SHARE_HISTORY` are turned off. The three options should be considered mutually exclusive."

Answer (score 2):

The original answer is mostly good, but to handle multi-line commands that also contain the character ':' for example this works:

```
local line_num_last=$(grep -ane '^:' ~/.zsh_history | tail -1 | cut -d':' -f1 | tr -d '\n')
local date_part="$(gawk "NR == $line_num_last {print;}" ~/.zsh_history | cut -c 3-12)"
local fmt_date="$(date -d @${date_part} +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')"
local command_part="$(gawk "NR >= $line_num_last {print;}" ~/.zsh_history | sed -re '1s/.{15}//')"
```

Comment: Cool! I haven't thought about multi-line commands. This is very helpful. Thank you so much! :-)

Comment: I add another line to make the multi-line commands stored as one-line commands: `local one_line_command=${(Q)command_part//\\$'\n'/}`. Now it looks really great. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to source something that will add persistent history for both bash and zsh, try this:

```
# You should source this file from both .zshrc and .bashrc

if [ -n "${ZSH_VERSION}" ]; then
    setopt append_history # append rather then overwrite
    setopt extended_history # save timestamp
    setopt inc_append_history # add history immediately after typing a command

    _get_line_num_last () {
      local attempts=0
      local line=0
      while true; do
        # Greps the last two lines that can be considered history records
        local lines="$(grep -anE '^: [0-9]{10}:[0-9]*?;' ~/.zsh_history | \
                     tail -n $((2 + attempts)) | head -2)"
        local previous_line="$(echo "$lines" | head -1)"
        # Gets the line number of the line being tested
        local line_attempt=$(echo "$lines" | tail -1 | cut -d':' -f1 | tr -d '\n')
        # If the previous (possible) history records ends with `\`, then the
        # _current_ one is part of a multiline command; try again.
        # Probably. Unless it was in turn in the middle of a multi-line
        # command. And that's why the last line should be saved.
        if [[ $line_attempt -ne $HISTORY_LAST_LINE ]] && \
           [[ $previous_line == *"\\" ]] && [[ $attempts -eq 0 ]];
        then
          ((attempts+=1))
        else
          line=$line_attempt
          break
        fi
      done
      echo "$line"
    }

    precmd() {
      local line_num_last="$(_get_line_num_last)"
      local date_part="$(awk "NR == $line_num_last {print;}" ~/.zsh_history | cut -c 3-12)"
      # Try to get date with non-mac date function.
      local fmt_date="$(date -d @${date_part} +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')" >& /dev/null
      # Try again with mac date function if that failed.
      if [ -z "$fmt_date" ]; then
          local fmt_date="$(date -r 1623959079 +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')" >& /dev/null
      fi
      # I use awk itself to split the _first_ line only at the first `;`
      local command_part="$(awk "
        NR == $line_num_last {
          pivot = match(\$0, \";\");
          print substr(\$0, pivot+1);
        }
        NR > $line_num_last {
          print;
        }" ~/.zsh_history)"
      if [ "$command_part" != "$PERSISTENT_HISTORY_LAST" ]
      then
        echo "${fmt_date} | ${command_part}" >> ~/.persistent_history
        export PERSISTENT_HISTORY_LAST="$command_part"
        export HISTORY_LAST_LINE=$((1 + $(wc -l < ~/.zsh_history)))
      fi
    }
elif [ -n "${BASH_VERSION}" ]; then
    log_bash_persistent_history()
    {
      [[
        $(history 1) =~ ^\ *[0-9]+\ +([^\ ]+\ [^\ ]+)\ +(.*)$
      ]]
      local date_part="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
      local command_part="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
      if [ "$command_part" != "$PERSISTENT_HISTORY_LAST" ]
      then
        echo $date_part "|" "$command_part" >> ~/.persistent_history
        export PERSISTENT_HISTORY_LAST="$command_part"
      fi
    }
    export PROMPT_COMMAND="log_bash_persistent_history"
fi

export HISTSIZE=1000000
export HISTFILESIZE=-1
export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T  "

alias persistent_history='cat ~/.persistent_history'
alias ph='cat ~/.persistent_history'
alias phgrep='ph | grep'
alias phg='ph | grep'
```